# Add Delete Button Dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have very little experience with Javascript.

My goal is to build a table from an array, and allow the user to delete items from the array as needed. I wanted to have a "delete" button next to each array item that is shown.

I'm open to other ideas of how to accomplish this. My code is here:

```
var LargeList = ["¥"]

function AddLargeItem() {
    LargeList.push(document.getElementById("LargeItems").value)

    LLen = LargeList.length;

    text = "<ol>";
    for (i = 0; i < LLen; i++) {
        text += "<li>" + LargeList[i] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ol>";

    document.getElementById("LargeInventory").innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById("LargeCount").innerHTML = LLen * 10;
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = LargeList.join("/ ");
}
```

The target HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
    <select id="LargeItems">
        <option></option>
        <option>LMIS</option>
        <option>ARMC</option>
        <option>BNCH</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="AddLargeItem()" id="AddLargeItem" value="ADD LARGE" />
    <span><p id="LargeCount"></p></span>
</div>
<p id="random"></p>

<p id="LargeInventory"></p>


</div>
```

Comment: Where is your table? What is the `TBDeleteLarge` input for? Why is your `LargeInventory` a `<p>` instead of an `<ol>`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan There isn't really a table. It's just an array displayed by loop. The "TBDelete" I should have removed, but was an approach that required user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to have a "delete" button next to each array item that is shown

To achieve your above requirement, you can modify the code as below.

```
<script>
    var LargeList = ["¥"]

    function AddLargeItem() {
        LargeList.push(document.getElementById("LargeItems").value)

        PopulateList(LargeList);
    }

    function PopulateList(arr) {
        LLen = arr.length;

        text = "<ol>";
        for (i = 0; i < LLen; i++) {
            text += "<li>" + arr[i] + "<input type='button' onclick='Delitem(" + i + ")' value='Delete' /></li>";
        }
        text += "</ol>";

        document.getElementById("LargeInventory").innerHTML = text;
        document.getElementById("LargeCount").innerHTML = LLen * 10;
        document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = arr.join("/ ");
    }

    function Delitem(index) {
        LargeList.splice(index, 1);
        PopulateList(LargeList);
    }
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works. I actually want to expand on the question, because I'm stuck again. You want me to mark you here and ask separately, or modify this question?

Comment: Hi @NickFleetwood, you can create a new thread for your new question.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways I can think of to do this.

num one:
assign the elements you want to delete and id ex:  then use javascript to append the elements with your list. then onclick="remove('list')" and make a function like this

```
function remove(id){getElementById(id).remove()}
```

num two:
if you just want to use javascript def your list then get an integer from the user and use my something like this

```
index = getElementById('foo').value;
my_list = my_list[:foo] + my_list[foo+1:];
document.write(my_list);
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusions. I would prefer option 1, but I'm not sure how to dynamically create the element with the onclick reference.